# Do I have to use the RabbitMqServer in order to get an instance of the RabbitMQ client?

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

Do I have to instantiate the RabbitMqServer inside of my hosting process in order to use the ServiceStack IMessageQueueClient?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you don't need to use `RabbitMqServer`, clients can create clients using `RabbitMqMessageFactory`, e.g:

```
var mqFactory = new RabbitMqMessageFactory();
var mqClient = mqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient();
```

Comment: Also note that RabbitMQ will be running somewhere as a service, in a similar way MySQL does. So you only need to be able to reach said server in order to connect, but RabbitMQ doesn't have to be running on the same server as the process.